# What stack should I choose?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

In my day to day work, I code WordPress themes, but have built very complex apps using no-framework php, also have used CodeIgniter to build very large applications, no stranger to node.js, mongoDB(and tons of other KV stores).

So now I need to build an application for a company that sells car parts, it will need:

- many products (with full stock management, ability to add products, ability to add shipments of products, each product may have options, such as different sizes, stock counts, pricing tiers)
- many clients (with stored client details and each may have their unique discount)
- ability for clients to purchase products with pdf invoice generation
- history of all actions performed by all users (don't mean clicking page to page, but product additions, purchases, deletions)

I'm thinking there's no point in using javascript/node as there's no need for concurrency, what I'm after is a framework that will save me time during initial setup and in the long run during build and maintenance.

I understand that Laravel is what's hot right now, but I've never played with it and am not sure if learning laravel is more time-effective vs using codeigniter, which I know pretty well (but just doesn't excite me any more).

Comment: have you considered not reinventing the wheel and go with a ecommerce CMS like prestashop/drupal/woocommerce/etc?

Comment: Try opencart http://www.opencart.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have played with Codeigniter, so i guess it will help you here.

You already know how easy it is to setup CI, also it has rich documentation so whenever you are stuck you can help you self.